# Lodash call function inside template

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using the `_.template` Lodash function and wanna know how to customize data values passed to it. I just wanna make something like (see toUpperCase()):

```
var compiled = _.template('hello ${ user.toUpperCase() } !');
compiled({ 'user': 'fred' });
```

Comment: Customize in what way?

Comment: Adding a customize function that will change the rendred value. Example of the previous example : put "FRED" instead of "fred", other example : put "10$" instead of "10" and so on. is that clear for you @Barmar ?

Answer (score 1):

Format inline Javascript that has a return string like so:

```
hello <%= user.toUpperCase() %>
```

*Note the `=` after the `<%`*

You can also run a block of code without necessarily outputting anything (though in this example I do inside the loop for kicks)

```
<% 
for (var i = 0;i < 10;i++){
%>
   Hello user # <%= i %>
   Welcome.
<% } %>
```

Comment: Where is `_.template()`?

Comment: All of this would replace the string the OP has.  So instead of `_.template('hello ${ user.toUpperCase() } !');` it would be `_.template('what I have here');` so:  `_.template('hello <%= user.toUpperCase() %>')`

Comment: @Deryck Thanks for your reply. I tried the suggested solution but that s not work for me. I have this error : Unexpected token {

Comment: @MariaMinh can you paste exactly what you have in your code into your original question or make a jsbin for me?  Here's one I made with the code running: https://jsbin.com/kazedipabu/edit?js,console

Comment: I added both inline JS as well as how you can achieve this using a script tag with an ID in your HTML